# Deploy Vespa.ai multinode to Kuberentes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, vespa

Looking for a solution to deploy multinode vespa to Kuberentes. I've refered docs but there is no info about deploying multinode to K8s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/examples/operations/basic-search-on-gke for a small multinode example - and feel free to submit improvements to both documentation and sample apps, it is a bit slim on Kubernetes. Kristian, Vespa Team

Comment: Hi Kristian, Thanks for above reference but not really helpful. Is there a step by step docs for deploying Vespa multinode to k8s cluster?

Comment: Sorry not that I know of, other than the singlenode guide at https://docs.vespa.ai/en/vespa-quick-start-kubernetes.html. We would love to have a multinode guide

Comment: Hi Kristian, Do you know how to feed multiple applications data to multinode vespa. After I activated one application data and fed documents. How can I activa another application data in Multinode vespa?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Refer to https://docs.vespa.ai/en/schemas.html#multiple-schemas for how to add more schemas for more applications / use cases (assuming this is what you mean by another application data)